# Italic fonts in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, labeling, cartography, print-composer, font

How can I apply italic fonts for labels and print composer in QGIS 3.4?

The option seems to be disabled.

Comment: Are you referring to the labels of a dataset attribute? Or a label in general when added as an item?

Comment: Yes, I can't choose Italic in QGIS 3.4+ (Windows 10) unless there's a specific Italic version of a font.  In MS Word Excel etc.I can change any font to Italics. An example is Sylfaen.

Answer (score 2):

To apply italic fonts for labels there are two ways to achieve this and depends on the type of label you are adding.

When you load in a dataset into QGIS, you can then go to the properties - labels tab and select if you would like to have label and from which field. There you can modify your font to *italic*. Once you create a new composer all your properties from the QGIS canvas will carry over. You will not be able to modify the label of a dataset once in composer.

[image]

Also, if you were to add any labels once in composer you will than be able to modify the font in the label tab once you select the label item.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had not noticed it depends on the font one is using, sinc enot all fonts support italic, bold, etc. Do you know how to change the default font in QGIS? Curiously, my version of the MS Shell Dlg 2 font does not support italic, only regular and bold.

Comment: That's a good question @Andres, I would suggest creating another question/post so that it is visible to the community and hopefully have an answer come in.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it depend on the font you use, for exemple on my setup Arial font let me choose 6 different style (normal, bold, italic, narrow, black and black italic) other font may have only the normal option or offer more than 10 different style depending on how they where created.

The way to access these option is by the style menu, not by clicking the "I" button that seem to be always disabled (I think you only use it for data defined override) .